# Express .post routing method undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs and express and I can't seem to phantom as per why this method isn't resolved in Webstorm. The .get method returns fine, testing it with the .all method works fine aswell. I have no clue why the .post method is unresolved, node starts up fine but if I try to send a post request to it through Postman it just gives an error:

[the Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wpIa.png)

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var routes = require("./routes");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`);
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/questions", routes);
// routes(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Express is running at", port);
});
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

// GET /questions
// Route for getting all questions
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        response: "You sent me an awesome GET request, thank you!"
    });
});

// POST /questions
// Route for creating a question
router.post("/questions", function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        response: "You sent me an awesome POST request, thank you!"
    });
    body: req.body;
});

module.exports = router;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "02-express-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: `var routes = require("./routes");` -- Great, you've imported a router... but you never attach it to your primary application router anywhere, so it's not used. You should be doing `app.use('/', routes);` somewhere, if you want to apply its routes to your main application at the root level. (Or uncomment `app.use("/questions", routes);` to attach the router to that path instead.)

Comment: Why `app.use("/questions", routes);` is commented ?

Comment: Uncommented `app.use("/questions", routes);`, still the same.

Comment: @cdhowie I've uncommented the `app.use("/questions", routes);` line, and it's still the same.The get method returns fine, the post does not. My IDE is also signalling that it's undefined (the .post method).

Comment: @Thomas-X Then something else is very wrong in your environment. I copied your code verbatim, uncommented the same line, and it works perfectly: `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/questions` ... `{"response":"You sent me an awesome POST request, thank you!"}` -- Are you restarting your node instance each time you make changes?

Comment: @cdhowie — Working for me too :)

Comment: @cdhowie Any idea as per what? Missing dependencies? I have no clue.

Comment: @Thomas-X The simplest possible explanation is that you are not restarting your `nodejs app.js` process each time you make changes. Please verify for us that restarting the application does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @cdhowie I am restarting it every time, still the same

Comment: @Thomas-X This makes me suspicious then that Postman is using a cached response and is not actually re-issuing the request. Try adding this global middleware right before `app.use(bodyParser.json());` -- `app.use(function (req, res, next) { console.log(\`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}\`); next(); });` This will have your server log out the requests it is receiving, and you can use it to verify that the server is even receiving any request.

Comment: @cdhowie It is receiving requests, tested with the middleware you posted. Here's the logs: `c:\gitrepos\nodejs\02-express-api>node app.js
Express is running at 3000
POST /questions
GET /questions
COPY /questions
POST /questions`

Comment: @Thomas-X Then I am stumped. Can you update the question with your updated code after making these changes?

Comment: @cdhowie Updated the code.

Comment: @Thomas-X `router.post("/questions",` should be `router.post("/",`, otherwise you need to POST to `/questions/questions`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: @cdhowie Yep, that fixed it. Wow, I feel like a dumb stick right now. There was this answer from before that's now deleted and I followed that, knowing it would probably be incorrect, I was desperate. Could you make an answer for it so I can mark it as correct? THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: @Thomas-X Done. What a trip this was. :) I suspect that you were always one step away from the right solution, but each time you fixed it you made some other breaking change at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.post("/questions",` should be `router.post("/",` for this to work; right now, that handler is responding to the URI `/questions/questions` since the router itself gets attached to handle URIs under `/questions`.